# MySQL - use a conditional with count?

Tags: mysql

I have the following sql statement:

```
select val, count(*) as tally from sometable group by val order by tally desc
```

Which produces the following (example) table:

```
val | tally
----+-------
4   | 20
5   | 10
6   | 5
7   | 3
8   | 2
```

Now, I want to only display the rows where `tally > 5`, so the result will be:

```
val | tally
----+-------
4   | 20
5   | 10
```

I tried this statement, but it does not work (it says "tally" is unknown):

```
select val, count(*) as tally from sometable where tally > 5 group by val order by tally desc
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try HAVING ([more information](http://www.techonthenet.com/sql/having.php)):

```
select val, count(*) as tally from sometable group by val having tally > 5 order by tally desc
```

Answer (score 0):

There are two approaches you can take:

1: Use `HAVING`. This means that the query results will be filtered as per the `HAVING` clause and only some of the original result rows will be returned to you:

```
SELECT val, COUNT( * ) AS tally
FROM sometable
GROUP BY val
ORDER BY tally DESC
HAVING tally > 5
```

2: Use a sub-select. This may give you better performance (I 'm no sql guru though so I can't say with confidence):

```
SELECT val, tally
FROM (SELECT val, COUNT( * ) AS tally
      FROM sometable
      GROUP BY val
      ORDER BY tally DESC)
      temp
WHERE tally >1
```